# How to get only ONE success or failure message for insertion query under while loop in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this insert.php as a part of my code and it works exactly the way i want it to except that, the echo texts get iterated until it comes out of the loop.
For example,if 3 rows are inserted, i get the message as "insertedinsertedinserted".

Is there a way where i could get more defined results such as

3 rows inserted or 3 rows not inserted.
Can someone help me on this?

```
 <?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'testdb');
$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);
if(!$dbcon)
{
    echo 'not connected to server';
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($dbcon,'testdb'))
{
    echo 'database not selected';
}

$rowIndex = 0;
$max = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'max');
while ($rowIndex < $max)    {    
$date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'date'.$rowIndex);
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user'.$rowIndex);
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE (DATE,USER) VALUES ('$date', '$user')";
if(!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql))
{
    echo 'not inserted';
}
else
{
    echo 'inserted';
}
$rowIndex++;
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Stop the loop when you encounter the first error.  Print the message after the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gordon, Assuming there's no error happening, how can i just make ONE message appear as "3 rows inserted" after the insertion has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you like to stop looping after something is wrong or go on. This is end of your code with loop stop:

```
    if(!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql))
    {
        echo 'not inserted';
        $isInserted = false;
        break; // to stop looping
    }
    //remove else
    $rowIndex++;
}
if($isInserted!==false){
     echo 'inserted';
}
```